# Proving that the char(R) is non-zero.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain and assume that for some non-zero $a \in R$, that $\exists n_a \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_a a = 0$. Prove that $R$ has non-zero characteristic.

So here is my thinking so far: I know that every field has characteristic zero or $p$ prime. Since we want to show that $char(R) \neq 0$, can we assume it's prime? If so, I think this is a proof by contradiction. Otherwise, I'm not really sure where to go.

Thanks :)

Comment: "Exists $\;n_a\;$..." *where*?

Comment: Ah. sorry. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repeated sum $n_aa$ is equal to $(n_a1_R)a$. This is a product of two elements of $R$ that is equal to $0$. Hence either $a=0$ or $n_a1_R=0$. Since by hypothesis $a\neq 0$, it follows that $n_a1_R=0$. This means that since there is some $n>0$ for which $n1_R=0$, there in particular exists a smallest one, and this is the characteristic of $R$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "repeated sum"? I'm not familiar with the term.

Comment: The notation $n_aa$ means $a+a+a+\cdots+a$, where there are $n_a$ terms in the sum. This is what I mean by repeated sum.

Comment: @Calculus08 Sure thing.